# C Program Takes Alphabetic Phones Numbers and Converts into Numberic Form

Tags: c

I'm working on a C code that will take an alphabetic phone number and convert into numbers. I'm stuck on the output. The output wil drop numbers needed. Such as 1-800-GATOR, will return 42867 but not 1-800-42867. This is what I have so far....

```
#include <ctype.h>  
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
char ch;
int num_vowels = 0;

printf("Please Enter a phone number: ");
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
         putchar('2');
         break;
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
         putchar ('3');
         break;
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':
         putchar ('4');
         break;
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'J': case 'K': case 'L':
         putchar ('5');
         break;
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'M': case 'N': case 'O':
         putchar ('6');
         break;
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S':
         putchar ('7');
         break;   
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'T': case 'U': case 'V':
         putchar ('8');
         break; 
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z':
         putchar ('9');
         break; 
    }

   printf("%c", num_vowels);


}

return 0;
}
```

Is it something that I'm missing in `printf("%c", num_vowels);`?

Any help is appricated!

Comment: Why given `switch (ch)` multiple times in `while` loop?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the `switch` statement. While your usage does perform correctly, you only need one statement with multiple cases:

```
switch (ch) {
    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
        putchar('2');
        break;
    case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
        putchar('3');
        break;
    case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':
        putchar('4');
        break;
    /*   ...   */
}
```

Note that nothing happens when the input doesn't match any of the cases. That's why only capital letters are transformed and sent to the output. One simple solution would be adding a `default` case. This way, when the input character is not any capital letter it is sent straight to output. Add this to the end of your `switch`:

```
switch(ch) {
    case 'A': case 'B':
    /* ... */
    default:
        putchar(ch);
        break;
}
```

You could perform other checks as well, only printing certain characters for example.

As for `printf("%c", num_vowels);` there is nothing wrong with it, except that `num_vowels` is never used. So you should expect it to print a null character (`'\0'`) after every character sent to output. I'm not sure about your intentions, but if it was a counter, you should increment the variable and print it only after reading input, outside the `while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char ch;
    int num_letters = 0;

    printf("Please Enter a phone number: ");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (isupper(ch)) num_letters++;

        switch (ch) {
            case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
                putchar('2');
                break;
            case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
                putchar('3');
                break;
            case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':
                putchar('4');
                break;
            case 'J': case 'K': case 'L':
                putchar('5');
                break;
            case 'M': case 'N': case 'O':
                putchar('6');
                break;
            case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S':
                putchar('7');
                break;   
            case 'T': case 'U': case 'V':
                putchar('8');
                break; 
            case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z':
                putchar('9');
                break; 
            default:
                putchar(ch);
                break;
        }

    }
    printf("\n-- %d alphabetic letters used.\n", num_letters);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `int ch` instead of `char ch` because `getchar` returns `int`. You should compare `ch` with `EOF` and handle that case.
2. Your code doesn't handle the case where a user enters a lower-case letter (e.g. `'a'` instead of `'A'`). You can correct this by using `ch = toupper(ch);`
3. You don't need to repeat each `switch()` statement.
4. `num_vowels` isn't being modified.
5. `printf("%c", num_vowels)` should be `printf("%d")` as `num_vowels` represents a human-readable number, not a character value.
6. `printf(...` should be after your `while` loop, not inside it.
7. You cannot use `getchar` and `putchar` to supplant user-input (i.e. disable local input echo), that requires platform-specific APIs. I recommend prompting the user to input a whole line of text first (into a `char*`), then process the line of text.

Comment: I don't understand #7. He's not trying to overwrite user input, he's just printing output based on the input. Because of input buffering by the terminal driver, none of the `getchar()` calls will execute until he presses Enter.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are wrong with how you are processing the input.
When you are taking input from the user i.e. 1-800-GATOR, you should skip the first 6 characters i.e "1-800-" and then start your switch case loop.

Also, the variable num_vowels is unchanged since you defined it till you print it. Why are you using it?

The code that will work for your statement will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
char ch;
//int num_vowels = 0;

printf("Please Enter a phone number: ");

while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    switch (ch) {
         case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
             putchar('2');
             break;
         case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
             putchar ('3');
             break;
         case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':
             putchar ('4');
             break;
         case 'J': case 'K': case 'L':
             putchar ('5');
             break;
         case 'M': case 'N': case 'O':
             putchar ('6');
             break;
         case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S':
             putchar ('7');
             break;   
         case 'T': case 'U': case 'V':
             putchar ('8');
             break; 
         case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z':
             putchar ('9');
             break;
    }
}
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The non-alphabetic part isn't necessarily 6 characters.

Comment: The problem statement has only one example so I have implemented it as said. It's not clear if the non-alphabetic part comes at the end or in between or is distributed.

Comment: It says "drop numbers as needed". He just wants to translate letters to numbers.